# Derivative sets $A'$

Tags: general-topology

i have this topological space: $(E,\tau)$ where $$\tau=\{U\subset E, x_0\notin U\}\cup \{U\subset E, E\setminus U ~\text{is at most countable}\}$$

where $E$ is an infinite set

If $A\subset E$ how to find $A'$ such that $$x\in A'\Longleftrightarrow \forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x, V\setminus\{x\}\cap A\neq\emptyset$$

thank you

Comment: What's "denonbrable"? Google finds nothing...

Comment: denombrable i.e finite impliese denombrable or there is a bijection  with $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @5xsum countable

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where does the expression denombrable come from? If it means "countable", does that mean the expression is from a foreign language?

Comment: from french : dénombrable

Comment: what is $x_0$ ? is  $x_0$ in U or E

Comment: When you say $\{U\subset E : x_0\in E\}$, do you really mean it? I read this as "the collection of all subsets $U$ of $E$ which satisfy the property that $x_0\in E$". Unless $x_0$ depends somehow on $U$, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: no $x_0\notin U$

Comment: @fonini $x_0$ is some fixed point of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

All points $x \neq x_0$ are isolated (as $\{x\}$ is open under the first condition). The only neighbourhoods of $x_0$ are the co-countable ones. (We can describe it as the one-point Lindelöfication of an uncountable discrete space; I will assume that $E$ is uncountable, or else $E$ is just countable/finite and discrete).

This already implies that no $x \neq x_0$ can be a limit point of any $A$, as $\{x\} \in \mathcal{V}_x$ and $\{x\}\setminus\{x\} = \emptyset$.

If $A$ is finite or countable, then if $x_0 \notin A$, then $E \setminus A$ shows that $x_0$ is not in $A'$, and if $x_0 \in A$, then $V_{x_0} = E \setminus (A \setminus \{x_0\})$ is open according to the second clause, and contains $x_0$, and $V_{x_0} \cap E = \{x_0\}$. So again $x_0 \notin A'$.

Now show that if $A$ is uncountable, $A' = \{x_0\}$.

Comment: so $A'= \emptyset $ if $A$ is countable  and $A'=\{x_0\}$ if $A$ is uncountable ? also i don't understand this " if A is countable , then if $x_0\notin A$ then $E\setminus A$ shows that $x_0$ is not in $A'$"

Comment: Yes. The latter is a neighbourhood of $x_0$ that misses $A$

Comment: why $V_{x_0} = E \setminus (A \setminus \{x_0\})$ is open please

Comment: Its complement is countable ($A \setminus \{x_0\}$).

Comment: please, if A is coutable and $x_0\in A$ , what is $\overset{\circ}{A}$, i think that it is $A\setminus\{x_0\}$ but i don't know how to prove that $x_0\notin \overset{\circ}{A}$

Comment: $E$ is infinite we have not that E in uncountable

Comment: No co-countable set fits in a countable set like $A$

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34719/discussion-between-vrouvrou-and-henno-brandsma).

Comment: if U is open and x_0\in U then $E\setminus U$ is countable , can $U\subset A$ such that $A$ is countable ?